# SimpleXML add node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to add Node to already created XML file. I've got an error **Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttribute() on a non-object**

```
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $xml->formatOutput = true;

    $Items =  $xml->Root->Items;

    $Item = $Items->addChild("Item",$desc);
    $item->addAttribute('id','99');
    $item->addAttribute('url',$img);

    $xml->asXml($file);
```

here's the structure of XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <TItle>Title1</TItle>

<Items>
    <Item id="2" url="/upload/1.jpg">description 1</Item>
</Items>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP variable names are case sensitive, so spot the difference:

```
$Item = $Items->addChild("Item",$desc);
 ^---upper case
$item->addAttribute('id','99');
 ^---lower case
```

So this error has absolutely NOTHING to do with SimpleXML.